# Android connecting to a Python Server

Tags: android, python, tcp

My buddy made a server in Python and wanted me to create an Android app that connects to it, but I have no idea where to start with that. Here's the code to the server. Can anyone help me out or put me on the right path?

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        a = data.split(':')
        print a
        if len(a) > 1:
            command = a[0]
            content = a[1]

            msg = ""
            if command == "iam":
                self.name = content
                msg = self.name + " has joined"

            elif command == "msg":
                msg = self.name + ": " + content

            print msg

            for c in self.factory.clients:
                c.message(msg)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []

reactor.listenTCP(5633, factory)
print "Chat Server Started..."
reactor.run()
```

Comment: If you're new to network programming, a good start will be reading up on the [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) and [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), [Berkeley's in particular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to network programming, a good start will be reading up on the [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) and [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), [Berkeley's in particular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets).

Once you have grasped the basic concepts, you'll want to check the [Android socket documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html), and finally try [a tutorial](http://micropilot.tistory.com/entry/Android-Socket-example)